# Как выводить определенное количество столбцов по запросу?

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть код, который генерирует таблицу с максимальным количеством столбиков в 31 день. Как можно менять это количество столбиков в зависимости от выбранной даты, там может быть и 31 день и 29 ,30 или 28.

Вот сам код :

```
<?php
    // 2018-08-02

    if(isset($_POST['dateList'])){
        $inp_inf = $_POST['dateList'];

    }else{
        $inp_inf = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    //echo $inp_inf;

    $car_year  = "2018" ; // 2018  
    $car_month = "08" ;   // 1-12   текущий месяц

    $number_days = 31 ; //  28,30,31     колличество дней минимум

    $tablheader = "<tr><td>Имя</td><td>Статус</td>"; // построение таблицы

    $i = 0;
    $w = "-" ;
    $day_w = 0 ;

    while($i++ < 31) {
        if($i <= $number_days ){

            $car_data = $car_year."-".$car_month."-".$i." 01:01:01" ;
            $tmp_data = strtotime($car_data); 
            $day_w = date("w",$tmp_data);

            if($day_w==1) {$w = "ПН" ;}
            if($day_w==2) {$w = "Вт" ;}
            if($day_w==3) {$w = "Ср" ;}
            if($day_w==4) {$w = "Чт" ;}
            if($day_w==5) {$w = "Пт" ;}
            if($day_w==6) {$w = "Сб" ;}
            if($day_w==7) {$w = "Вс" ;}


            $tablheader = $tablheader."<td>".$i." / ".$w."</td>" ;
        }else{
            $tablheader = $tablheader."<td> --- </td>" ;
        }
    }

    $tablheader = $tablheader."</tr>";   
    echo $tablheader;
?>
```

**ЗДЕСЬ ВВОДИТСЯ НЕОБХОДИМАЯ ДАТА**

```
<select name="dateList">
    <option>2018-08-01</option>
    <option>2018-02-01</option>
    <option>2018-04-01</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="ok">
```

Comment: Вместо константы 31 посчитать количество дней в месяце. Т.е. тупо: плюс месяц, минус день, взять номер дня.

Comment: И что с этого выйдет ? Пока что не очень представляю , на теории может и должно работать но на практике...

Comment: И на практике тоже будет работать.

Comment: можете на моем примере показать ?

Comment: а то я в <option> выбираю дату и делаю отправку ,а таблица не меняется ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$inp_inf = date('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime($inp_inf);
echo $date->format('t');
```

Comment: А в скайпе пропал )

Comment: Типа эта часть меняется ?  
if(isset($_POST['dateList'])){
    $inp_inf = $_POST['dateList'];
    $date = new DateTime($inp_inf);
    
}else{
    $inp_inf = date('Y-m-d');
}

echo $date->format('t');

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex эта часть вставляет вместо `$number_days = 31 ; //  28,30,31` и всякие `$car_year` и `$car_month` достать от туда-же

Comment: зайди ко мне пожалуйста ...пароль 4383